# How to bypass cve-2020-26160 vulnerability in dgrijalva/jwt-go?

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

Container Security state does not pass in Gitlab pipeline because of one high level vulnerability. This vulnerability is jwt-go and it's installed version is `v3.2.0+incompatible`. The error title like this: `jwt-go: access restriction bypass vulnerability-->avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2020-26160`. The Go version of the relevant repo is `1.16.3`. How can I fix this vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CVE-2020-26160](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-26160) vulnerability is due to the fact that `dgrijalva/jwt-go` incorrectly models the JWT `aud` field as a `string`, when based on the [JWT specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) it should be a slice of strings.

> In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-sensitive strings

You can't bypass it yourself, because it's a bug in the library: https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/428

Switch to the [official](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/462) community fork [`golang-jwt/jwt`](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt), its `v3.2.1` fixes the vulnerability: https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/releases/tag/v3.2.1

> - Import Path Change: See MIGRATION_GUIDE.md for tips on updating your code
>   Changed the import path from github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go to github.com/golang-jwt/jwt
> - Fixed type confusion issue between string and []string in VerifyAudience (#12). **This fixes CVE-2020-26160**

Answer (score 0):

github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go solved this vurnability 25 days ago, the version you use (v3.2.0) is from 2018, updating to use the latest version of that library should solve all the jwt security problem

Comment: Why does everyone always say "update" but not "update, and here's how." This answer is fine -- it's accurate, but it's not useful.

Comment: because updating a library is the same as installing it, it is something very trivial to do

Comment: Not for everyone.